# Efficient way to find highest value from predicates

Tags: efficiency, prolog

I have predicate, that enumerates through backtracking list of values. I want to find highest value from this list.

For example:

```
ranked_move(X,Y,R) :- between(0,10,Y), between(0,10,X), rank_move(X,Y,R).
top_move(X,Y) :- % X, Y for highest R
```

Right now, I have it solved by using `findall` and custom predicate that goes through the list and remembers highest value it comes across. But I would like to know if there is way to do it without first turning the moves into a list. Eg. do the picking predicate directly on `ranked_move`.

I know about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701693/max-out-of-values-defined-by-prolog-clauses . I haven't tried it, but I assume Prolog is not going to go through the predicates efficiently.

Comment: I just noticed I posted this on Programmers, not on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't have any way of judging your moves except calling `ranked_move/3`, no, there is no more efficient way than calling it on everything and finding the maximum of the resulting list.

It would be possible to avoid the `findall` by writing your own predicates that generate the values systematically and remember the maximum so far, and so avoid the overhead of creating a list. But that overhead is very likely insignificant next to the cost of judging the moves (no heuristic worth implementing could possibly be cheaper than a cons operation).

So the only really useful improvement would be to have a different, cheaper, weaker heuristic that influences the order in which the moves are *generated*, and iterate over them in an order more likely to have the maximum first. (Even then, of course, you would still not terminate any quicker unless you set a cutoff value that is "good enough" rather than "optimal".)

Comment: You are right. I was focusing on wrong part of the problem.